# how is a slack bot activated

Tags: bots, slack-api

I'm very new to Slack, but need to create a quick demo that can be triggered from any channel (private as well).  So I created a custom slash command which works well.  Now I have to reply back to a private channel (not the calling channel), and maintain state while a conversation is orchestrated.  I think I'm on my way to creating a Slack Bot, I'm not sure how the Slack Bot should be activated - is the pattern to use a slash command to a bot, which then has an auth token which can open a private channel?  How do I break the slash command request reply cycle, from the request reply cycle of the bot interaction?

I'm finding the creation and patterns around Slack Bots a little light, while the rest of the documentation is easy to understand - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's matter of perspective IMO.  Messages that are created from a bot perspective are delivered from that perspective.  A Slack bot however can also send messages using their real-time API, and acts more like a "normal" user on slack.  For example a Slack bot can be invited to Teams, and then review who is on the team, and send messages to the team. Messages come from the bot as if the bot was a person, as opposed to bot that relying messages.

This is my perspective at the moment, as I'm learning Slack integration.  As nobody provided an answer, this is what I know at this point in time.